# MYSQL query relut based on cuttent time

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Query to get list of records between stating time and end time

Ex:

```
Start_time    End_time 
----------------------

22:00         05:00

20:00         02:00
```

If i query in between the time have to get those result am **not using any date specific**. i used Now() Between not worth any one have good idea

Comment: It is not clear what your result set should be. Do you want all rows where the row-wise start and end times surround your criteria? Please post a larger row sample and a sample of what query output you hope to achieve,  with your attempted query.

Comment: If run the query any time - to get the records those the current time is in between start and end .. Start time start from 22:00 end with 05 means next day morning .. but not have any date there .. that case have to find

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i')](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to get `HH:MI` string from date and then compare it with `start_time` and `end_time` depend on `start_time>end_time` or not.

```
SET @start_time = '22:00';

SET @end_time = '05:00';

select *
  from T 
  where (
            (@start_time<=@end_time) 
            AND (DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i') >= @start_time)
            AND (DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i') <= @end_time)
         )
         OR
         (  (@start_time>@end_time) 
            AND 
            (
              (DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i') >= @start_time)
              OR
              (DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i') <= @end_time)
            )  
          );
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c50153/15)</kbd>